# Identify this bug attacking rose buds

Tags: pest-damage

The buds on two of my rose plants are being attacked by something that damages the outer petals. I've been spraying with an organic pesticide but it doesn't seem to be having much effect. What can effectively treat this?

[image: Damaged rose bud]

[image: Damaged yellow rose bud]

Comment: Has your  weather been pretty wet lately? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: I live in Bangalore, India. There has been a day or so of rain but it's mostly very hot, around 32 deg celsius

Answer (score 1):

My first thought, before even seeing the picture, that came to mind was possible thrips damage.  But you have also said very hot and organic pesticides.  I don't live in India but have found that on hot summer days in Illinois we have to watch all types of pesticides organic or not, especially if they are oil-based in the heat.  the trick is not to damage the plant more than the bug will.

Do yourself a favor and treat in early cooler temps of the day or if lucky on cloudy days for less damage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I spray in the evenings but will keep this in mind

Comment: in my area we tend to spray in the mornings because with the humidity issues you increase the chances of fungus by spraying in the evenings when it is cooler and going to dry slower.  if at all with the high humidity.

Answer (score 1):

The temperatures are very high here in summer and the sun is very strong, so spraying in the morning is not advised. But I will try doing so when the monsoon comes and humidity is very high. Meanwhile, I saw some tiny black insects on one bud yesterday and sprayed immediately. I looked up thrips on the Net and it does look like that could be what is damaging the buds.